# how to use the text of a Entry in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, get, copy

I need the text of an entry that I want to output with print()

the Entry is e_out

```
from tkinter import * from tkinter import filedialog import os def resample():

    e_out = StringVar()
    
    os.system('ffmpeg -i "'+ filename + '.mp4" -vf "tblend=all_mode=average,framestep=2,tblend=all_mode=average,framestep=2"
-r 60 '+ e_out + '.mp4')
    os.system("cls")
    

def file_browser():
    
    global e_out
    global filename
    global resample
    root1 = Tk()
    root1.geometry("600x400")
    e_out = Entry(root1).pack()
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/Videos", title="Select A File", filetypes=(("videos", "*.mp4"),("all files", "*.*")))
    print(filename)
    b1 = Button(root1, text="resample", command=resample).pack()
    root1.mainloop()



global root root = Tk() 
root.geometry("800x500") 
root.title("intler") 
choose = Button(root, text="choose a file", command=file_browser).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: [edit] your question and format the code properly (not as quote as it currently is but as code with \`\`\` at top and bottom of the code), as of now it is not very readable, also what is the issue? btw layout manager methods return None so really `e_out = None`

Comment: Use `Toplevel` for the second window, not `Tk`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the text in an entry box by using the line:

e_out.get()

this will return a string with text in the entry box